# como guardad codigo html completo como TEXT en base datos mediante AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax, text

tengo codigo html, necesito mediante AJAX, al darle boton ej:Guardar, que todo el codigo se guarde en la base datos en un campo tipo TEXT

Comment: 0

votar en contra



¿Entiendo que te refieres a que tienes un textarea en el que introduces código HTML y quieres guardar el contenido en una bbdd?

Comment: es un ejemplo, yo tendria codigo completo :$content = '<html>
<head>
  <script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <style>--Some Styling--</style>
</body>
</html>';

Comment: y a traves de un boton guardarlo tal que asi en una bbdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola podrías poner tu código html dentro de un div, y con el ajax obtener su contenido para mandarlo a la BD.

Algo así:

```
<div id="divConHTML">
  .......codigo html
</div>
```

y el ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "mandaraBD.php",
                    data: {
                        'html' : $('#divConHTML').html(),
                    },
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                    }
});
```

Comment: es un ejemplo, yo tendria codigo completo :
$content = '<html> 
<head> 
<script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
 <title></title> 
<style>--Some Styling--</style>
</head> 
<body> 

 </body> 
</html>';
a traves de un buttom .

Comment: en madaraBD.php que se haria?, uso symfomy3

Comment: perfectoo!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias pasar los datos mediante ajax a PHP y este imprimirlos en un txt.

Prueba con lo siguiente:

-AJAX:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#save').live('click', function() {
    var dataString = 'data='+$('textarea#data').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "writetxt.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
            $('form').remove();
            $('.content').append('<p>Tu texto se ha guardado correctamente!</p><a href="data.txt" target="_blank">Ver</a>');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

-PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("classes/class.inputfilter.php");
 $ifilter = new InputFilter();
$data = $ifilter->process($_POST['data']);
$file = 'data.txt';

if (isset($data)) {
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fp, utf8_decode($data));
fclose($fp);
chmod($file, 0777);
echo 'Se han guardado correctamente la información en el txt!';
 }
 else {
echo 'No hay datos que guardar!';
}
?>
```

Comment: es un ejemplo, yo tendria codigo completo :
$content = '<html> 
<head> 
<script>--Some javascript and libraries included--</script>
 <title></title> 
<style>--Some Styling--</style>
</head> 
<body> 

 </body> 
</html>';
a traves de un buttom .